# APPCRASH clr.dll with Exception Code: c0000005?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, clr

My application use WPF, Managed C++ code on .Net Framework 4.5. When deploy and run on machine's client, sometimes It crashed with following message

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name: MysticServer.exe
    Application Version: 1.0.0.0
    Application Timestamp: 545c4e2a
    Fault Module Name: clr.dll
    Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4ffa59b1
    Exception Code: c0000005
    Exception Offset: 000000000000953d
    OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
    Locale ID: 1033
    Additional Information 1: 2110
    Additional Information 2: 21108e23475d6b696ac6aa3910059a97
    Additional Information 3: dbb7
    Additional Information 4: dbb72edca07efeeeb70560c121df6016
    http://1.0.0.0/
    1.0.0.0
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I installed on client machine .Net 4.5, Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013.

Before that, I installed only .Net 4.5 and Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013. But the app crash on start up. I have to install Redistributable 2010, 2012, 2013 then my app can start successful.

Client machine is Windows 7 64bit, and my app has built as 64bit application.

Someone can tell me how to fix the above crash issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Someone can tell me how to fix the above crash issue?`  Debug your program.  You're just wasting time installing and uninstalling applications.

Comment: I can not debug on client machine, when run on development machine, I can not reproduce this bug!

Comment: So you're saying you weren't ready to debug or diagnose problems if they didn't appear on your machine?  Isn't that what you are supposed to be prepared for if you release an application to the public?  What about producing log files, crash dumps, etc.?

Comment: @TTGroup Download WinDbg. Copy (no need to install) it to the client machine. Attach it to your process and debug it. If you've never used WinDbg, it has a steep learning curve. But there are many online resources. It is essential for debugging production issues that do not reproduce on development machines.

Comment: Is it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10347696/709537) perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397075/how-do-i-debug-an-environment-specific-bug